# Is it possible to extract an SSRS report embedded in the body of an email and export to csv?

Tags: python, html, csv, email

We currently are receiving reports via email (I believe they are SSRS reports) which are embedded in the email body rather than attached.  The reports look like images or snapshots; however, when I copy and paste the "image" of a report into Excel, the column/row format is retained and it pastes into Excel perfectly, with the columns and rows getting pasted into distinct columns and rows accordingly.  So it isn't truly an image, as there is a structure to the embedded report.

Right now, someone has to manually copy and paste each report into excel (step 1), then import the report into a table in SQL Server (step 2).  There are 8 such reports every day, so the manual copy/pasting from the email into excel is very time consuming.

The question is: is there a way - any way - to automate step 1 so that we don't have to manually copy and paste each report into excel?  Is there some way to use python or some other language to detect the format of the reports in the emails, and extract them into .csv or excel files?

I have no code to show as this is more of a question of - is this even possible?  And if so, any hints as to how to accomplish it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"possible to extract"*: Yes, *"export to csv?"*: Yes

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution is to have the SSRS administrator (or you, if you have permissions) set the subscription to send as CSV. To change this in SSRS right click the report and then click manage. Select "Subscriptions" on the left and then click edit next to the subscription you want to change. Scroll down to Delivery Options and select CSV in the Render Format dropdown. Viola, you receive your report in the correct format and don't have to do any weird extraction.

Comment: Thanks for your response - unfortunately I was told we can't do this since we're getting the reports from an outside vendor and the contract would have to be amended to change the existing process, which would take awhile.  This is a more urgent issue, so they were looking for a workaround in the meantime.